# Why no russia-stackoverflow data in Stack Exchange Data Dump (August 18, 2015)

Tags: bug, data-dump, russian-stackoverflow

I found that recently Stack Exchange updated their data dump in [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) but I do not find data about [Russia-Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). I can find similar ones such as data dump of [Japanese-Stackoverflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) and [Portuguese-Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) but why no data dump about ru-stackoverflow? I can only find the data dump of meta-ru-stackoverflow as below:
[image]

Does Stack Exchange forget to release the data about this site? or any other reasons? Can anybody tell me why or how to remind Stack Exchange about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The site isn't part of the [sites.xml](https://ia800500.us.archive.org/22/items/stackexchange/Sites.xml) as well so I assume that site wasn't included in the export process.

Comment: @rene Thanks for your reply. But why its meta data is there? By the way,  do you know when it will be put into such list?

Comment: A developer prepares the dump and has to schedule and run the batch job. I'm not sure who is responsible but bugs reported here are seen by SE Developers so I assume you'll get some response from them. But be prepared to accept that you'll have to wait until the next refresh to get that missing data included.

Comment: Yeah, something strange going on here. The scripts that generate the 7z files for the dump do have ru.so there, so something between us and archive.org went wrong (this isn't limited to ru.so - there are 11 missing files altogether).