# Why no softwareengineering.stackexchange data in Stack Exchange Data Dump (March 14, 2017)

Tags: bug, data-dump

I can't find [softwareengineering.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) data in latest Stack Exchange Data Dump (March 14). I don't know how to report this 'bug', but found a [related post about missing Stack Overflow in Russian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266220/why-no-russia-stackoverflow-data-in-stack-exchange-data-dump-august-18-2015) and the 'bug' was fixed in the next release, so I think another post here will help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is there, only under the old name of the site - programmers.

`programmers.stackexchange.com.7z` is what you are looking for - we did not change the database name, which is why the data dump contains that.

We may be able and change it in the future, but it isn't trivial to do while keeping the site online...

Comment: Thank you for keeping us online. :)

Comment: I see a way to turn a crisis into an opportunity here. What if we change the database name when the next outage happens (if it happens at all) or the servers are taken down for the next maintenance?

Comment: @dorukayhan I think that there are more important things to do when there is a server outage.